# omnetpp run error :"make: *** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop."

Tags: c++, omnet++

omnetpp version: 6.0.2
os: mac 13.3.1 (a)

console message:

```
11:29:46 **** Incremental Build of configuration release for project tictoc ****
make MODE=release all
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
"make MODE=release all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
11:29:46 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 392ms)
```

cpp code:

```cpp
simple Txc1
{
    gates:
        input in;
        output out;
}
network Tictoc1
{
    @display("bgb=267,291");
    submodules:
        tic: Txc1;
        toc: Txc1 {
            @display("p=158,182");
        }
    connections:
        tic.out --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> toc.in;
        tic.in <-- {  delay = 100ms; } <-- toc.out;
}
```

what I tired:
Originally there was only clang, but later I installed and used gcc-13.